# Make Firebug console history persist upon browser exit

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug

Whenever I've used the developer tools in Chromium or Google Chrome, my command history in the console has persisted when I've exited the browser and restarted it. That is, if I type

```
console.log('Remember me');
```

in the Chrome console, exit Chrome, start Chrome, reopen the console, and press the 'up' arrow on the keyboard, it shows `console.log('Remember me');` in the console and I can press Enter to execute the command again.

I've just moved to using Firefox at work, have installed Firebug, and would like the same console behaviour that I experienced on Chrome. Firebug similarly lets me scroll up in the console to commands that I've executed *since opening Firefox*, but if I close and reopen Firefox, the command history in Firebug gets blanked and I can't access my previously typed commands by pressing the 'up' key.

Can I configure Firebug so that the command history will persist upon restarting Firefox, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not possible. Though there's an enhancement request for this in [issue 4276](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4276).

Note that Firebug is [open source](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/), so if you feel up to it, you can provide a patch for it.